# Freezing Functions based on time (GAS or Detault Functions)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, countif, timed

I'm trying to find a way to execute a formula at a specific time and then lock it, without changing.

Essentially, I am counting responses for different people (from the output of a google form). Each week, the google form is wiped. However, I want to keep the record of how many times said persons name came up in the last 8 weeks.

Right now, I simply use a COUNTIF() function and manually tally the results. I'd like to improve this system and switch over to some way where it is kept in different cells/sheets, and then once the end of the week hits that COUNTIF would just print the absolute value of it's result and freeze.

I'd be ok to do this using Google Apps Script if necessary as I have some proficiency with that. In the interest of time though, using some kind of built in Google Sheets method is preferable.

Please let me know if this has been done or if there are ways to get this done (I'm sure it's doable, not sure how).

Comment: There is no built-in method to accomplish this.

Comment: @I'-'I recalcution settings work for function like now() but it's recalculated on any change.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of formulas at an specific time and then "freeze" the result depends on the characteristics of the formulas

Cases

1. **custom function with static arguments**
   Add a  dummy argument that should be changed at the time that the custom function should be recalculated. Since custom functions can't use volatile functions as arguments, a time-driver trigger should change the dummy argument at the desired time.
2. **built-in functions** with or without custom functions
   Use a time-driven trigger that adds the formula wait for the spreadsheet recalculation finish and then replace the formula by it's result.

Bear in mind that time-driven triggers will not run at very precise times.

Comment: interval is +/- 15 minutes, which is pretty precise in the context of "weekly". And once started, the interval between activations is pretty consistent